# fPortfolioBacktest could not be installed

Tags: r

I could not install the **fPortfolioBacktest**.

Because the [link](https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=156) is missing. Only Linux and Mac are available.

to install:

```
install.packages("fPortfolioBacktest", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
```

I have the below error messages:

```
package ‘fPortfolioBacktest’ is available as a source package but not as a binary
```

Warning message:

> package ‘fPortfolioBacktest’ is not available (for R version 3.0.0)

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

With R 3.0.0, if you have all the dependencies for **fPortfolioBacktest** installed, you can install it from source by specifying `type=source`:

```
install.packages("fPortfolioBacktest", repos="http://r-forge.r-project.org", 
                 type="source")
```